# Locally Convex Topology on $C_b(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and look at $C_b(\Omega)$. Then we can define a topology $\tau$ on this space by being the finest locally convex topology agreeing with the compact open topology on sup-norm-bounded sets. But how to understand this topology. What kind of seminorms one has for this topology, what properties has this topology? Thank you very much.